# How do I disable the Skype shutdown sound on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype, system-sounds

The question says it all. How can I get rid of that irritant?

I have tried through control panel with no success and cannot find a solution for it.

Comment: I believe it is actually Skype shutting down. So I don't run Skype.

Comment: Thank you. It is obviously Skype. I went into Skype sounds and turned off the logout sounds, quit Skype to check the sound (no sound), rebooted and again no sound. Please make your comment an answer so I can accept it. Another problem has occurred; now Skype will not connect. I'll try to fix that now. :)